# Calculate significant digits of a number in R

Tags: r

Maybe a daft question but why does R remove the significant 0 in the end of a number? For example 1.250 becomes 1.25 which has not the same accuracy. I have been trying to calculate the number of significant digits of a number by using `as.character()` in combination with `gsub()` and regular expressions (according to various posts) but i get the wrong result for numbers such as 1.250, since `as.character` removes the last 0 digit. Therefore the answer for 1.250 comes out as 2 digits rather than 3 which is the correct.

To be more specific why this is an issue for me:

I have long tables in word comprising of bond lengths which are in the format eg: 1.2450(20):

[image]

The number in parenthesis is the uncertainty in the measurement which means that the real value is somewhere between 1.2450+0.0020 and 1.2450-0.0020. I have imported all these data from word in a large data frame like so:

```
df<-data.frame(Activity = c(69790, 201420, 17090),
               WN1=c(1.7598, 1.759, 1.760),
               WN1sd=c(17, 15, 3))
```

My aim is to plot the WN1 values against activity but also have the error bar on. This means that i will need to manually convert the WN1sd to: `WN1sd=c(0.0017, 0.015, 0.003)` which is not the R way to go, hence the need to obtain the number of significant digits of WN1. This works fine for the first two WN1 values but not for the 3rd value since R mistakenly thinks that the last 0 is not significant.

Comment: There's a clear distinction between what a value *is* and how it is *displayed*. There are a few options that impact how a number is represented on the console, such as `options(c("digits","scipen"))`.

Comment: In your example 0 is not a significant digit. Unless specified otherwise, the standard output of any programming language will drop that zero. You might want to look into `?formatC` for options to display a number.

Comment: If you want the zero,   you could use `sprintf("%5.3f", 1.25)`

Comment: @RHertel That 0 is definitely significant. Maybe not in programming language (which i find very odd) but certainly in sciences. For example when we say 5 mL the uncertainty is at the 5 which means that the measured value could be 4 or maybe 6 mL and was measured very roughly. However, 5.00 mL is much more accurate and measured with high accuracy equipment. I will update my question to make it more clear what the exact problem is.

Comment: I agree that in the case of scientific *measurements* with limited accuracy, the 0 might indeed be significant. In a programming context such numbers have a different meaning in the sense that their accuracy or their number of significant digits is not determined by the user input but by floating point arithmetics.

Comment: @RHertel I see what you mean. This is quite an interesting and unexpected situation for me! Will take a closer look again in formatC and also what r2evans suggests as we speak.

Comment: You say that you import data from a word file. Maybe this is the step where you can set the standard deviations right by counting the number of chars of the WN1 numbers. Edit your question and show us the pattern of your text file and how you import it into R

Comment: @pietrodito Done, i used regular expressions to separate the numbers in parentheses out.

Comment: This is the step where you can count number of digits after the dot separator in WN1 numbers. With that you can multiply the sd number to the right power of ten...

Comment: @pietrodito You mean to do that in the word document? I am not exactly following.

Comment: @G5W I am not sure this will work for me as i want R to measure the number of significant digits (scientifically speaking) automatically, rather than me setting it manually. So something like using: `nchar(gsub("(.*\\.)", "", x))` where x is the value in the data frame. Interestingly if you replace x with say '1.500' it works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to prepare the standard deviations at the time you import your data from your word document

There's a point where you should have strings like that :

```
"1.2345(89)" "4.230(34)" "3.100(7)"
```

This is a function you can apply to those chars and get the sd right:

```
split.mean.sd = function(mean.sd) {
   mean <- gsub("(.*)\\(.*", "\\1", mean.sd)
   sd  <- gsub(".*\\((.*)\\)", "\\1", mean.sd)
   digits.after.dot <- nchar(gsub(".*\\.(.*).*", "\\1", mean))
   sd  <- as.numeric(sd)*10^(-digits.after.dot)
   mean <- as.numeric(mean)
   c(mean, sd)
   }
```

For example:

```
v <- c("1.2345(89)","4.230(34)","3.100(7)")
sapply(v, split.mean.sd)
```

gives you

```
     1.2345(89) 4.230(34) 3.100(7)
[1,]     1.2345     4.230    3.100 
[2,]     0.0089     0.034    0.007
```

Comment: That is dead on, i understand exactly what you meant now (and a bit gutted i didnt think about it as well :) ). Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Most programming languages, R included, do not track the number of significant digits for floating-point values. This is because in many cases significant digits are not necessary, would significantly slow down computations and require more RAM.

You may want to be interested in some libraries for computations with uncertainties, like the [`errors`](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1804.08552.pdf) (PDF) package.